# Why am I only get last rows value in foreach loop java enterprise

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am a beginner of Java enterprise programming, now I am aiming to do a food order system. I displayed all records from database into a table inside jsp page. Now i want to get the record of each row that I have selected into database, but the problem is I only can submit last record inside my arraylist. Is there anyone can give some help?

```
<table>
        <tr>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Price</th>
           <th>Restaurant</th>

           <th>Add to Cart</th>
        </tr>
          <%
           List<FoodRecord> foodDisplay =
                   (List<FoodRecord>)
                   session.getAttribute("foodDisplay");

           if(searchResult == null){


            for(FoodRecord foodRecord: foodDisplay)
           {
           %>



        <tr>   
            <td><%=foodRecord.getName()%></td>
            <td><%=foodRecord.getPrice()%></td>
            <td><%=foodRecord.getRestaurant()%></td>
            <td>
                <form action="cost" method="post" name="menu">
             <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" name="order"/>
           <%
               session.setAttribute("id", foodRecord.getFoodId());
               session.setAttribute("name", foodRecord.getName());
               session.setAttribute("price", foodRecord.getPrice());

            %>
            </form>
             </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`session.setAttribute` can only save one value. The way you have coded now, the values are overwritten and when the page is posted to the browser only the last values are stored in the `session` object.

If you use hidden fields then each form will hold its own values and they will be posted in with the form:

```
       <form action="cost" method="post" name="menu">
           <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" name="order"/>
           <input type="hidden" id="id" value="<%=foodRecord.getFoodId()%>"/>
           <input type="hidden" id="name" value="<%=foodRecord.getName()%>"/>
           <input type="hidden" id="price" value="<%=foodRecord.getPrice()%>"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: I put your code inside my page, but the table row becomes into blank

Comment: Fixed: I have removed some commas that shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're setting it to the last values:

```
           session.setAttribute("id", foodRecord.getFoodId());
           session.setAttribute("name", foodRecord.getName());
           session.setAttribute("price", foodRecord.getPrice());
```

You need parameters, not attributes:

```
 <form action="cost" method="post" name="menu">
     <input type="submit" value="Add to cart" name="order"/>
     <input type="hidden" value="<%=foodRecord.getFoodId()%>" name="id"/>
     <input type="hidden" value="<%=foodRecord.getName()%>" name="name"/>
     <input type="hidden" value="<%=foodRecord.getPrice()%>" name="price"/>
 </form>
```

You'll get them at the receiving end with request.getParameter("id"), etc...